# facebook user & friend permission not showing up on scopes

Tags: facebook

I have a simple login app to utilize oAuth for facebook.
I will need to access a few things about the user so i added a few parameters in the
`User & Friend Permissions`

[image]

I waited over 24 hours for the servers to propagate but when i debug the token, i dont see these permissions added to the scope
[image]

**I grabbed the token by:**

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 
        'appId'  => '**************',
    'secret' => '**********************************'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $token;


if ($user) {
    try {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        $album = $facebook->api('/me/albums ');
        print_r($album);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>php-sdk</title>
        <style>
            body { font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
            h1 a { text-decoration: none; color: #3b5998; }
            h1 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>php-sdk</h1>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div>
                Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h3>PHP Session</h3>
        <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <h3>You</h3>
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

            <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
            <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
        <?php else: ?>
            <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!--h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture"-->
        <?php //echo $naitik['name']; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?
any help please, thank you.

Comment: And this is actually a token that you acquired by visiting your app in one of the ways that trigger _Authenticated Referrals_? Or did you just do a “normal” login? (When doing that, you have to ask for the permissions via the scope parameter.)

Comment: That does not really answer my question, in which way you entered the auth dialog for your app – was it via Authenticated Referrals or not?

Comment: @CBroe im not understanding your question, where would i find this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals – if you did _not_ go to your app in one of these ways, but did trigger the login/connect yourself, then the settings shown in your screenshot get not applied (of course), and you have to set the scope yourself.

Comment: so you are saying that the creater of the app(which is me) has to login with my credentials to put all of this into motion?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14532/discussion-between-t-q-and-cbroe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing needed permission after user installed make you need to ask for the new permission.

So you can uninstall and install again, or make a JS to check if your user have the necessary permission and, if not, ask using FB.ui

Comment: i am the creator of the app, i went into developers page and added permission just like the photo shows.  what other steps are required? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: you can refresh your token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ click in get access token and check the permissions you want in the selected app. But you can too uninstall the app from your user profile, and not from app center. So, when you access your app again, you will need to grant the new permission.

Comment: yes!  i have used the explorer in the past but the token that is granted seems temporary. also, how do you uncheck the boxes?

Comment: for me, the token is updated when a use the explorer. you have more users in your app than you ?

Comment: i meant when i login oAuth, the Authenticated Referrals does not refresh for other users

Comment: So, how i said before, you need use JS SDK FB.ui to ask your users to update they permissions.

Comment: i see,  is it possible with PHP?

Comment: No, PHP SDK is only for retrieve data and send data. For authentification you need use JS